# Streamline Private NPM workflow

Tags: npm, private, streamline

As our project grows and more components are shared between them we realised that we need a private npm. The technical side of setting it up was straight forward, but we now faced with questions on how to streamline development team work around that, when to published, how to version, should developers work with a local copy of the private project?

Really keen to hear from your experience.

Comment: so interested in this topic, and I would love to see a recommendation

Comment: And the deafening silence. :-(